# I am trying to use a find function to find room and assign a name to the adjacent cell, however I am getting a code 91 in the debugger

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use a find function to find room and assign a name to the adjacent cell, however I am getting a code 91 in the debugger. I have used this find function multiple time and it has flawlessly worked but when I set it to a new variable and changed the sheet and userform reference, it just stopped working.

The lay out is on sheet3 there is a list of all of the room numbers A:A, and I want a a code to find the room number assigned in the userform and add the name of the person to the second column B:B.

```
'Update Occupancy List
Sheet3.Select
Dim FndRng As Range
Set FndRng = Sheet3.Columns("A:A").Find(What:=AddOccupant.txtRoom.Value,  LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext,     MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
FndRng.Offset(0,1).Value = txtName.Value
```

Comment: Is the value actually found?

Comment: Yes it is. I have also used the exact same find function on other lists and it works great. but i just can't get this one to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error 91 is "Object variable or With block variable not set"

The only undeclared variable I can see here is [AddOccupant] which I assume is the UserForm with the [txtRoom] text box. If my assumptions are correct then you need to declare a form first

Dim frmX as UserForm
Set frmX = [Whatever the form name is]

and mod the search line :   ...(What:=frmX.txtRoom.Value,...

BTW, .Value is a universally default so you do not have to be explicit, that is "frmX.txtRoom.Value" and "frmX.txtRoom" are the same.

Comment: The name and caption of the userform is AddOccupant. Isn't that a correct reference? Or should I still declare it? and thank you for letting me know, I will leave that out in the future.

Comment: Yes, it's a correct way to reference a form. I was hoping to expose the possible syntax problem... If this is not the issue then the "txtName" is the next choice. What is it? Where/how is it declared?